# As an interviewer, asking a candidate to find errors in small sample code. Is this fair?

Tags: interview

We've been interviewing on and off for about two years, and I've run this by about 30 candidates. I wrote some 20 lines of code which perform a relatively basic operation, but has a bunch of errors in it. None of them are syntax errors. Errors range from bad memory management, incorrect data types, multithreading problems, misuse of keywords, and a couple functional errors that would give undesired output.

People get *really nervous* during this question. Is it a fair question to be asking? The goal is to get an idea of their comfort level with the language (Objective C has some very strange behaviors, and most applicants we get are relatively inexperienced in ObjC specifically as compared to other languages), as well as see their ability to recognize logical problems in otherwise foreign code.

Once a candidate has made a first pass, I often will point to specific lines that have remaining errors on them and see how much hand-holding it takes to get a correct identification and/or fix from them.

At our company, this is a real world scenario, as programmers would be thrust straight into a 100k line app and given bugs to fix, and we need people that are comfortable with working with the code of 6 other programmers.

However, today, another of our interviewers told me he hated this problem (I didn't quite understand what his reason was, admittedly). Is this something I should continue asking, or should I look for alternate avenues?

Comment: Are you using any libraries in the test code other than basic standard ones?

Comment: Only standard libraries, and all standard code. Well, there is one fairly obscure enumeration method in there, but I leave it in to see if candidates will either a) already be familiar with it (good sign), or b) inquire as to what it does or figure it out and just roll with it.

Comment: How many people do well on this code challenge?

Comment: I've run it past a couple team members with no help and they did fine. Candidates haven't been as good, but those that have struggled haven't done well on other questions, either, and we've had exceptional difficulty finding good programmers in a general sense anyway, so I tend to think it speaks more to our problems even getting talent into the interview room than the question being particularly difficult.

Comment: @puzzl: Maybe run it by other people *not* in your company who are familiar with Objective-C? Maybe it needs to be simplified a bit, or broken into separate smaller, independent challenges - some more difficult than others.

Comment: I think the word "fair" in terms of interview questions is not quite right.  It is better for both the company and the prospective employee that only the right matches are made.  Keeping this in mind may result in very different questions than what candidates find comfortable.  It's better to have people go away thinking a question was "unfair" than to hire them because you avoided hard questions and then fire them six months later.

Comment: Of course it's fair. If you can't find mistakes in code you're not going to do well at the job

Answer (score 17):

This is perfectly fair. Reading code is inherently easier than writing code, so checking if they can do the most basic of professional tasks is a pretty important part of an interview. For junior candidates it may be tough to expect them to debug something on paper, as they're likely reliant on debuggers still. If you could have the broken program on a computer, that might be better.

I don't buy the whole "pressure situation is unfair" argument either. Clients and/or bosses will inevitably be breathing down your candidate's throat when some critical issue is found. How they work under pressure is part of evaluating how they'll do at the job.

All that said, some good people won't do well at this sort of thing. They're not critical, or they are more deliberate (or collaborative), or they're simply inexperienced with your particular problem (simple or not).

That doesn't make it less fair - you just need to be sure to account for other things as well.

Comment: Doing it on a computer is an interesting idea. I wonder if it would then make the problem too easy? A bunch of the errors will most certainly be called out by the compiler. That in-and-of-itself isn't necessarily a problem, but Xcode will give you a fix, too, which is no good, as the candidate should know what the fix is, not just click the button and not necessarily know why that fixes something.

I guess, though, that it's certainly a more realistic scenario. And some people definitely do work better *after* the crash than before. Maybe I'll consider this approach.

Comment: I have a coworker who asks this sort of question, and says "let me act as your debugger".  He'll tell them any state information they want to know about how the code executes.

Comment: @StevenBurnap - I've seen that in a few places and it can work well, but often takes the tone of showing off or being a conflict between the candidate and the "debugger" (like they probably have with real debuggers).

Comment: Actually, I've found that reading code tends to be much _more difficult_ than writing it, except in some few cases where the code is very elegant and clean. But as you say, reading code is an important task that you'll want a candidate to be able to do.

Comment: +1 for everything except "Reading code is inherently easier than writing code" - Boy, i've had to read and "decrypt" terrible-terrible code time and again. Reading code is *not* easier than writing code. Unless of course the code in question is either extremely well constructed, is too simple and isn't performance optimized.

Comment: You don't think someone printing off some code, dropping it off at your desk and then expecting you to find all the issues without a computer in a limited time window whilst management look on is unfair? Are you the "Code Warrior" the ancients speak of? :)

Comment: I hope that you give them a own paper with the problem. Also give them a pen. Make sure that they understand that they can get a couple of minutes to "compile" the code. And finally invite them to think out loudly and discuss the code.

Comment: @techfoobar Definitely. I agree with the "fundamental law of programming", as stated by Joel S. :) "It’s harder to read code than to write it."

Comment: @RobbieDee as an interview question it's not necessarily about finding all the issues or not, win or lose. It's also about how one approaches the task, their thinking process, their strategy etc.

Comment: @KonradMorawski Forgive me, but my comment was made in jest I can assure you... :)

Comment: @RobbieDee http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m3eik3ycqD1qzdf1oo1_400.jpg ;)

Comment: @techfoobar (et al) - Enh. If you give me some language I've never used before and tell me to fix this bug, I'm probably going to be able to step through and fix the bug. If you give me a language I've never used before and tell me to implement something, the latter is always going to be tougher to accomplish. Not only do you need to write the code, but then you get to fix the bugs too.

Comment: You will more likely than not read more of others code in your carer, particularly so in the beginning.  This a must have.  Its a much fairer than say write code to balance a btree on a white board.  One its a problem you will never have to solve and the other you will never code on a whiteboard.

Comment: @Telastyn - Code reading assignments if given, must be either in algorithmic/pseudo-code OR it must be in a language that the candidate is experienced in. Otherwise I think is unfair on the candidate. You cannot short-list a pure Java developer for a job that required debugging python code.

Comment: Reading and refactoring others' code, is something the candidate will likely be doing a lot on the job, so including it in a interview is not only fair, but essential imo.

Answer (score 3):

As an aside, I'd be interested to hear why the other interviewer thought the problem was inherently unfair, but on to the meat of your question:

It rather depends on what you're trying to achieve. If your goal is to recruit an Objective C guru, then the test is clearly fair.

However, if you're just looking for a journeyman Objective C programmer then perhaps not. Is the code typical of what they'll find in your organisation or purely an academic exercise? Certain types of code problems sometimes vary from organisation to organisation.

Also, how the test is staged could be a factor:

- Are they told how many issues are in the code?
- Are they timed?
- Are the interviewers sat in the room or are they left alone?
- Are they allowed to ask questions?

Whilst you point out that they'll be expected to fix such problems day to day, they won't be doing this from a source code print out.

The acid test of course is whether you're getting the right sort of staff once they jump through the hoop. If you are, then I'd be inclined to stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not whether it is "fair" or not but whether the test a) is eliminating candidates who do not have the skills needed for the job and b) letting through those candidates who do. As long as the test does this job well, you should continue asking it.

The details of the test depend on the needs you have and the standards you want to maintain. When I show to a candidate a piece of code where a database API call could raise an exception if the record is absent but the code that uses the API call is written to treat *all exceptions* raised by the call to mean "record is absent", I'd expect any candidate fit for *any* job I offer to point out that the code is swallowing exceptions. I don't have a position for someone who cannot see this problem.

One way to lessen the opportunity for uneasiness could be to just have an extremely simple coding test before having the "find the errors" test. Once candidates pass the initial documentary check (i.e. their résumé looks good), I find that most candidates that don't make it through are failing at the simple coding test stage.